# On Mac OS X, do you use the shipped python or your own?

Tags: python, macos, installation

On Tiger, I used a custom python installation to evaluate newer versions and I did not have any problems with that<sup>*</sup>. Now Snow Leopard is a little more up-to-date and by default ships with

```
$ ls /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
2.3    2.5    2.6    @Current
```

---

- What could be considered best practice? Using the python shipped with Mac OS X or a custom compiled version in, say `$HOME`.
- Are there any advantages/disadvantages using the one option over the other?

---

<sup>My setup was fairly simple so far and looked like this: Custom compiled Python in `$HOME` and a `$PATH` that would look into `$HOME/bin` first, and subsequently would use my *private* Python version. Also `$PYTHONPATH` pointed to this local installation. This way, I did not need to `sudo`–install packages - virtualenv took care of the rest. Note: I liked this setup, so I'm just curious and thought I inquire the *hive mind*.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it depends on your needs. Personally, I use the latest version for any series (2.5, 2.6, etc.) from MacPorts.

Answer (score 2):

I compile it myself because this gives me the newest 64-bit version. The official OS X builds seem to be 32-bit only. I dropped MacPorts several months ago because its dependency system and its often outdated packages were too annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the Python version that's shipped with your OS is that it may contain bugs, or be limited in other ways.  If you install Python from Fink or MacPorts, you have the liberty of updating it.

Another, important advantage of managing your own version of Python with a package manager (Fink or MacPorts) is that they help a lot with the **compilation of module dependencies** (for instance when you use a module that depends on compiled C code).  Thus, installing Python modules is certainly easier if you do not use the Python shipped with OS X.  This is an important point to consider, before making your choice.

Answer (score 0):

What you do on your on machine is totally up to you. If you're going to deploy your code to other people's, I'd say it's clearly preferable to use the shipped version unless you *really* need the newer version.

Comment: I disagree. Most packaged python software ships python inside the package, and that's the right way to do. God knows what the user installs on his machine.

Comment: @unbeli If you're distributing a substantial application, OK. But for a few scripts? Exactly how many python interpreters does a machine need, anyway? And more generally, how does it make sense *not* to code for the baseline environment if all else is equal?

Comment: Well, scripts are not really "deployed", so there is no way to bundle python. There is no baseline you can trust here. I know it sucks, but that's life, no one promised it's not going to suck ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm digging up this old topic.

There are no real answers to create your own python distro/framework from source and bundle and package it in a correct way. I tried to compile it from source, linking it against my C programmed application which uses python 3 and works on my computer. But when I move it around the filesystem (e.g to /tmp) it has hardcoded paths in the python compile. And I have no clue what script/wrapper to make.

My point to ship our own python distro is to make sure there is no oddness in interpeter change involved when shipping the application and rely on the OS python install.

It is also nowhere documented on the python docs.

I already found this post [4206511](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206511/launch-python-into-a-mac-application)