# How to bundle Python into a macos .app application?

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

I have a software written in python with a graphical user interface written in PyQt.

To create an executable of the software, I ship with it a Python and a Qt precompiled version and the trick seems to work in Windows and Linux since I know how to create an installer.

The problem is to embed evrything into a Mac `.app`.

To launch the software I use the following shell script

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=`pwd`/Resources
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:. bin/python ProgramPy/Main.py
```

If I run this shell script from outside it works fine, but when I try to embed everything into an app with platypus I get the following error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/luca/Desktop/TempScript.app/Contents/Resources/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
./run.sh: line 3:   725 Trace/BPT trap          PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:. bin/python ProgramPy/Main.py
```

Note that the file `/Users/luca/Desktop/TempScript.app/Contents/Resources/bin/python`
is the executable version of python and it is actually located into the Resources folder of the app. I don't understand why the system cannot find it. Maybe I missed something in understanding how mac uses the pythonpath?

Answer (score 3):

I just use [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html).